# itextsharp convert points to cm

Tags: c#, itext

I am using `iTextsharp` - a java pdf lib - to generate pdfs dynamically.
Now as I understood it, measurements are specified in points. I know where to place what on the place in cm.
so I need the conversion:
points <-> cm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

iText(Sharp) has a `Utilities` class (package `com.itextpdf.text` / namespace `iTextSharp.text`) which contains several static conversion methods, in particular:

```
// iText
public static final float millimetersToPoints(final float value);
public static final float millimetersToInches(final float value);
public static final float pointsToMillimeters(final float value);
public static final float pointsToInches(final float value);
public static final float inchesToMillimeters(final float value);
public static final float inchesToPoints(final float value);

// iTextSharp
public static float MillimetersToPoints(float value);
public static float MillimetersToInches(float value);
public static float PointsToMillimeters(float value);
public static float PointsToInches(float value);
public static float InchesToMillimeters(float value);
public static float InchesToPoints(float value);
```

Your assumption that *measurements are specified in points* is only partially correct but in your use case *to generate pdfs dynamically* that's good enough.

In general, though, measurements are specified in **user space units**, and the default user space unit (i.e. before any transformations are in place) can be configured on a per-page basis to be any float multiple (subject to implementation specific limitations) of 1/72 inch:

> **UserUnit**
>   number
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.6)* A positive number that shall give the size of default user space units, in multiples of 1⁄72 inch. The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent.
>
> Default value: 1.0 (user space unit is 1⁄72 inch).

*[(Table 30, section 7.7.3.3, ISO 32000-1)](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)*

Due to that default your assumption holds if nothing else is selected.

Comment: How to use this methods?? I want to use `MillimetersToPoints`. But I am unable to get this method in my code. Can you please help me??

Comment: `pointsValue = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(mmValue)` should do the trick.

Comment: @ml Thanks! Worked on VB.NET too!

Comment: Is there something similar for iText 7?

Comment: @mkl sure, it's trivial. However, I would have liked to use "batteries included". I ended up copying the class from iText 5 