# Split part of the PDF horizontally

Tags: java, android, image, pdf, itext

[image: Click Here for Image Reference]

I am working with iTextG 5.5.8 and Android. I have to split part of the pdf into Two Horizontal views. I can't use **PdfPTable** because I want left side fully an image and right side fully a Table. Also, I have to present the image in 25mm*12mm size. Can anyone hide me on the right path to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning why you *can't use PdfPTable*.

Comment: @mkl if I use pdf table (cell) means the first cell will print image and one line of text in the right side. Then the remaining lines will come to the right bottom of the image.

Comment: How about using the left cell for only the image and the right cell for the table? Or a table with the left cell with rowspan across all rows with the image and the remaining cells for the table on the right?

Comment: @mkl left side if I use an image in the cell, right side I can able to use only one line, then other lines will come bottom of the image only. But I want to place all the 4 lines on the right side of the image. Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple ways to achieve that:

#### One table with rowspan use

Assuming you have loaded your image into `Image image` and you add to a `Document document`:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[]{2,1,1});

PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell(image);
imageCell.setRowspan(4);
imageCell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(imageCell);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address1"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP | Rectangle.LEFT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Contact Number"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP | Rectangle.RIGHT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address2"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Fax"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address3"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Pin Code"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address4"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM | Rectangle.LEFT);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM | Rectangle.RIGHT);
table.addCell(cell);

document.add(table);
```

*([CreateTable](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/CreateTable.java#L44) test `testSureshOneTableRowspan`)*

#### Two tables

Again assuming you have loaded your image into `Image image` and you add to a `Document document`:

```
PdfPTable innerTable = new PdfPTable(2);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address1"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Contact Number"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address2"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Fax"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address3"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Pin Code"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address4"));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
cell.setBorder(0);
innerTable.addCell(cell);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell(image);
imageCell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(imageCell);

table.addCell(innerTable);

document.add(table);
```

*([CreateTable](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/CreateTable.java#L104) test `testSureshTwoTables`)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just now I also got this exact way from my brother and working on that. I have one doubt, If I use the image in the cell, the image getting full to the entire cell(image getting bigger), but I want to keep the image in the original size. Is it possible?

Comment: You can restrict the image size using e.g. `image.scaleToFit(110,110)`.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the image to particular mm(Mili Meter) size like 30mm(w) * 12.2mm(H)

Comment: @Suresh Simply use the number of points corresponding to those 30mm or 12.2mm. Look e.g. [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14598795/1729265).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any calculation to get the exact point for 30mm(w) * 12.2mm(H)? or manually we have to use point like (image.scaleToFit(x,y)) and test to get the exact size?

Comment: 2.54cm = 1 in = 72 points. Thus, 30mm = (30/25.4) in = 72 * (30/25.4) points. And 12.2mm = 72 * (12.2/25.4) points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167102/discussion-between-suresh-and-mkl).